# Find non recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have a recursive function defined by $a_{n+1}=2 a_n + 1$. I am trying to find a non recursive formula from it, but I have no idea how. The first terms are $a_1= 1$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=7$, $a_4= 15$, and $a_5=31$. I don't seem to find a pattern at all.

Comment: Things are getting "twice as big" each time, or at least close to it.  What other ways of talking about "twice as big" do you know?  The powers of $2$ get twice as big each step of the way as well...

Comment: The term you want to search for is "linear inhomogenous (or nonhomogenous) recurrence relation (with constant coefficients)". There are very general methods to solve these; some discussion can be found online e.g. [here](https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/S/1019/Website_files/21-linear-recurrences.pdf). Alternatively, just notice that each of your terms is $1$ off from a power of $2$, and do induction.

Comment: OEIS is always a good bet. https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C7%2C15%2C31&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add 1 to each term, you get:

$$a_1 + 1 = 2$$
$$a_2 + 1 = 4$$
$$a_3 + 1 = 8$$
$$a_4 + 1 = 16$$
$$a_5 + 1 = 32$$

Does the sequence ring a bell?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= 1 \\
a_2 = 2*1 + 1 &= 2 + 1 \\
a_3 = 2(2+1) + 1 &= 4 + 2 + 1\\
& ...
\end{align*}

The pattern is more clear when viewed from this angle